# Unterschied zwischen »festnehmen« und »verhaften«

Tags: difference

> 4 Personen wurden am Montag nach einem Bombenanschlag in Barcelona festgenommen.
>
> 4 Personen wurden am Montag nach einem Bombenanschlag in Barcelona verhaftet.

Beide Wörter bedeuten *to arrest.* Sind sie austauschbar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Meines Erachtens nach hängt es davon ab, ob ein Haftbefehl vorhanden ist oder nicht.

Sollte bereits ein Haftbefehl vorhanden sein, so wird er von der Polizei *verhaftet*. Wobei hier auch *festgenommen* verwendet werden kann.

Ist kein Haftbefehl vorhanden, so wird die Person festgenommen. Letztendlich entscheidet dann ein Richter, ob die Person in Haft geht.

***Verhaftet* sollte verwendet werden, wenn zu dem Zeitpunkt klar ist, dass die
Person in Haft geht.**

Sicherlich kann über einige Zwischenfälle wie *in Gewahrsam nehmen* oder *Untersuchungshaft* noch weiter diskutiert werden.

Answer (score 5):

Das ist eine juristische Frage. Die Begriffe »anhalten«, »festhalten«, »festnehmen«, »inhaftieren«, »verhaften« usw. sind in Gesetzen genau geregelt. Da die Schweiz, Österreich, Deutschland, und andere Länder, in denen Deutsch eine Amtssprache ist, diese Begriffe unterschiedlich definieren, bedeuten diese Wörter je nach Land auch etwas anderes.

So hat z.B. in Österreich jeder Bürger die Möglichkeit eine andere Person an der Flucht zu hindern, wenn diese eine Straftat begangen hat. Wenn man also beobachtet, wie jemand etwas stiehlt, dann darf man diese Person bis zum Eintreffen der Polizei, die in diesem Fall zwingend zu verständigen ist, an der Flucht hindern. In Österreich heißt das »Anhalten«. Man hält einen Verdächtigen an.

Soviel ich weiß (Achtung, Vermutung!) heißt derselbe Vorgang in Deutschland »Festnehmen«. In Österreich kann eine Festnahme nur durch einen Beamten der Exekutive (also einen Polizisten) erfolgen, vom grundsätzlichen Wesen her (Fluchtverhinderung) sind aber die Anhaltung und die Festnahme dasselbe.

Gleich ist meines Wissens aber die Bedeutung von »Haft« und daher von »Verhaften«. Damit ist der Vorgang gemeint, dass man eine Person von Exekutivorganen in einen eigens dafür vorgesehenen Raum (eine Gefängniszelle) steckt. Jemand, der verhaftet wurde, ist auch automatisch ein Häftling. Jemand, der nur festgenommen, aber nicht verhaftet wurde, ist kein Häftling.

Festgenommen kann jeder ohne richterlichen Beschluss werden. Um jemanden zu verhaften, braucht man aber einen Haftbefehl, der nur von einem Gericht ausgestellt werden kann. Wenn jemand festgenommen wurde, und der Haftbefehl nicht innerhalb einer gewissen Frist (ich glaube 48 Stunden) ausgestellt wird, wird die Festnahme unzulässig, und die festgenommene Person ist spätestens nach Ablauf dieser Frist wieder in die Freiheit zu entlassen.

Zur Ergänzung: Zum Sträfling wird man erst durch das Verhängen eines rechtskräftigen gerichtlichen Urteils. Daher wird in Gefängnissen auch zwischen Häftlingen und Sträflingen unterschieden. Wer in Untersuchungshaft sitzt und auf seinen Prozess wartet, ist kein Sträfling, sondern nur Häftling.

Comment: Deine in deinem dritten Absatz geäußerte Vermutung trifft zu. Das sogenannte Jedermann-Festnahmerecht in Deutschland ergibt sich aus [§ 127 der deutschen Strafprozessordnung (StPO)](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stpo/__127.html).

Comment: Zumindest das deutsche Recht kennt m.W. den Begriff *Sträfling* nicht mehr.

Answer (score 3):

Es mag einen juristischen Unterschied geben (*anhalten* wäre auch noch eine Möglichkeit), aber in der Presse und dem Alltagsgebrauch handelt es sich um vollständige Synonyme.

**Nachtrag** aus österreichisch-juristischer Sicht:

Eine *Anhaltung* kann hierzulande prinzipiell von jedermann durchgeführt werden, egal ob von Exekutive oder Staatsbürgern (zum "Anhalterecht Privater" siehe § 80 öStPO). Diese *vorläufige Verwahrung* ist dabei weniger formalistisch als die Verhaftung, und auch nur für 24 Stunden (ausnahmsweise 48 Stunden) zulässig.

Einer *Verhaftung* liegt prinzipiell, aber nicht immer (Gefahr im Verzug), ein Haftbefehl zugrunde. *Festnahme* ist  ein Synonym zur Verhaftung. So auch recht deutlich das [Bundeskanzleramt bei help.gv.at](https://www.help.gv.at/Portal.Node/hlpd/public/content/246/Seite.2460304.html). Das gilt erst Recht für den laiensprachlichen Gebrauch.

Comment: Kannst Du Beispiele zeigen, wo es in der Presse lax verwendet wurde?

Comment: Nimm eine beliebige deutschsprachige Tageszeitung und suche nach "verhaftet" bzw. "festgenommen." Wenn es einen Unterschied gibt, erschließt er sich mir als Leser nicht.

Comment: Das habe ich gemacht und von den ersten 5 Treffern bei Google-News 4 besucht, die 'verhaftet' beinhalten, alle 4 sprechen auch von Haft oder Haftbefehlen. Nr. 2 wäre der Postillion gewesen, den ich aus nahe liegenden Gründen nicht in Betracht gezogen habe. Da eine Verhaftung auch eine Festnahme ist, macht die Gegenkontrolle keinen Sinn. Wenn Du beschlossen hast den Unterschied zu ignorieren folgt daraus nicht, dass alle anderen ebenso ignorant sind, zumal die Presse sonst mit Gegendarstellungen zu rechnen hat.

Comment: _Ad hominem_ Argumente kommen immer gut, wenn man keine anderen hat... Für Ö könnte ich (neben der muttersprachlichen Sprachkompetenz, die sich nur schwer quantifizieren bzw. Außenstehenden vermitteln lässt) noch die Strafprozessordnung zitieren, in deren § 181 die Begriffe als vollständige Synonyme behandelt werden ("Wenn der Beschuldigte nach seiner Freilassung gegen Sicherheit seine Flucht vorbereitet oder wenn neue Umstände hervorkommen, die seine **Verhaftung** erfordern, so ist er ungeachtet der Sicherheit **festzunehmen**,  doch wird in diesen Fällen die Sicherheitsleistung frei.)

Comment: Die öst. Strafprozessordnung spricht übrigens bevorzugt von Festnahme, und zwar ausdrücklich auch auf Anordnung ("Die Festnahme ist durch die Staatsanwaltschaft auf Grund einer gerichtlichen Bewilligung anzuordnen und von der Kriminalpolizei durchzuführen.") Inwiefern das daher dem dt. Begriff "Verhaftung" entspricht müsse andere beurteilen.

Comment: Ah, jetzt, wo ich die Belege über die Presse gebracht habe, genügen diese nicht mehr - interessant. Stattdessen meinst Du belegen zu können, dass ein Synonym vorliegt, weil der weitere Begriff der Festnahme für eine Verhaftung verwendet wurde - alleine, das hat niemand bestritten. Dass man das Nicht-wissen-wollen Ignoranz nennt ist keine Erfindung von mir, und dass Du nicht gewillt bist, einen Unterschied festzustellen, hast Du selbst eingeräumt. Du könntest Dich ja durchringen diese I.abzulegen. Ich präzisiere aber gerne, dass Du in Hinblick auf dieses eine Wort i. bist, aber nicht generell.

Comment: Du scheinst, wie manche Deiner Landsleute, Schwierigkeiten mit Deutsch als plurizentristischer Sprache zu haben, was eben auch bedeutet, dass der eigene Sprachgebrauch nicht immer und überall das Maß aller Dinge ist. Ich erlaube mir daher ebenfalls zu präzisieren: zumindest **in Österreich** wird in der Presse und der Öffentlichkeit zwischen Verhaftung und Festnahme nicht unterschieden. Ich weigere mich nicht, einen Unterschied zu erkennen, ich _kann_ es nicht (Hypothese: weil es keinen gibt.) Und damit, was mich betrifft, EOD.

Comment: Und hast Du denn für Deine These einen Beleg in Form von Presseartikeln? Oder ist das nur eine gefühlte Wahrheit?